# Python - Sorting a Tuple-Keyed Dictionary by Tuple Value

Tags: python, dictionary, key, tuples

I have a dictionary constituted of tuple keys and integer counts and I want to sort it by the third value of the tuple (key[2]) as so

```
data = {(a, b, c, d): 1, (b, c, b, a): 4, (a, f, l, s): 3, (c, d, j, a): 7}
print sorted(data.iteritems(), key = lambda x: data.keys()[2])
```

with this desired output

```
>>> {(b, c, b, a): 4, (a, b, c, d): 1, (c, d, j, a): 7, (a, f, l, s): 3}
```

but my current code seems to do nothing. How should this be done?

**Edit:** The appropriate code is

```
sorted(data.iteritems(), key = lambda x: x[0][2])
```

but in the context

```
from collections import Ordered Dict 
data = {('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'): 1, ('b', 'c', 'b', 'a'): 4, ('a', 'f', 'l', 's'): 3, ('c', 'd', 'j', 'a'): 7}
xxx = []
yyy = []
zzz = OrderedDict()
for key, value in sorted(data.iteritems(), key = lambda x: x[0][2]):
    x = key[2]
    y = key[3]
    xxx.append(x)
    yyy.append(y)
    zzz[x + y] = 1
print xxx
print yyy
print zzz
```

zzz is unordered. I know that this is because dictionaries are by default unordered and that I need to use OrderedDict to sort it but I don't know where to use it. If I use it as the checked answer suggests I get a 'tuple index out of range' error.

**Solution:**

```
from collections import OrderedDict 
data = {('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'): 1, ('b', 'c', 'b', 'a'): 4, ('a', 'f', 'l', 's'): 3, ('c', 'd', 'j', 'a'): 7}
xxx = []
yyy = []
zzz = OrderedDict()
for key, value in sorted(data.iteritems(), key = lambda x: x[0][2]):
    x = key[2]
    y = key[3]
    xxx.append(x)
    yyy.append(y)
    zzz[x + y] = 1
print xxx
print yyy
print zzz
```

Comment: dictionaries are unsorted

Comment: Dictionaries can be sorted when iteritems is called though.

Comment: @JonathanConnell: That doesn't mean you can get your desired output.

Comment: So why are you using `data.keys()[2]`? The key order is arbitrary, whatever key at index 2 is should not inform your sort. And **all** your items are sorted on the basis of that one key. Did you mean `x[0][2]` perhaps (so the first element of the `(key, value)` pair or `key`, then the third element in that tuple).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dictionaries are unordered in Python. You can however use an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

You then have to sort like:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

result = OrderedDict(sorted(data.iteritems(),key=lambda x:x[0][2]))
```

You need to use `key=lambda x:x[0][2]` because the elements are tuples `(key,val)` and so to obtain the `key`, you use `x[0]`.

This gives:

```
>>> data = {('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'): 1, ('b', 'c', 'b', 'a'): 4, ('a', 'f', 'l', 's'): 3, ('c', 'd', 'j', 'a'): 7}
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> result = OrderedDict(sorted(data.iteritems(),key=lambda x:x[0][2]))
>>> result
OrderedDict([(('b', 'c', 'b', 'a'), 4), (('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), 1), (('c', 'd', 'j', 'a'), 7), (('a', 'f', 'l', 's'), 3)])
```

**EDIT**:

In order to make `zzz` ordered as well, you can update your code to:

```
data = {('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'): 1, ('b', 'c', 'b', 'a'): 4, ('a', 'f', 'l', 's'): 3, ('c', 'd', 'j', 'a'): 7}
xxx = []
yyy = []
zzz = OrderedDict()
for key, value in sorted(data.iteritems(), key = lambda x: x[0][2]):
    x = key[2]
    y = key[3]
    xxx.append(x)
    yyy.append(y)
    zzz[x + y] = 1
print xxx
print yyy
print zzz
```

Comment: The actual problem is the sort key, which you fixed but didn't explain.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: that's why they invented something as [edit]. To first give an answer the op can test, and then explain. So that less time is wasted if the answer does not meet the expectations :). I notice you actually nearly always do the same :)

Comment: The [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/43070905/revisions) of the post show that the `key=lambda x: data.keys()[2]` version was there in the first 5 minutes.

Comment: There is an unusual caveat though: I am using this to say 'for key, value in sorted_dict: x = key[2], y = key[3] etc. For this, it reverts back to being unsorted even though if I print sorted_dict it is alphabetically sorted.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: what do you mean? That are the question revisions. The answer has only two reversions, both were `x[0][2]`...

Comment: @JonathanConnell: that's because `for key,value in sorted_dict` iterates over the **keys**, not the **items**..

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood your first comment then and was discussing the question.

Comment: @JonathanConnell: if I look `list(result.iteritems())`, I get `[(('b', 'c', 'b', 'a'), 4), (('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), 1), (('c', 'd', 'j', 'a'), 7), (('a', 'f', 'l', 's'), 3)]`. Looks quite sorted.

Comment: See my edit. It is sorted - the issue is that I am "appending" from this into ANOTHER dictionary which is unsorted. I confused an error with the latter parts of the code with the initial question asked.

Comment: @JonathanConnell: but as specified in the answer: a *dictionary* is *unoredered*. You have to make `zzz` an `OrderedDict` as well ito maintain order at that level.

Comment: I've got it. I didn't know you can define a variable (or rather a dict before it's a dict) as OrderedDict()...

Comment: @JonathanConnell: I updated the answer. Now `zzz` should remember the order as well.

Answer (score 3):

Your key function is completely broken. It's passed the current value as `x`, but you ignore that and instead always get the second item from the list of keys.

Use `key=lambda x: x[0][2]` instead.

Comment: I think you have to use `x[0][2]` since the `iteritems()` emit (key,value) tuples.